# How to close one fragment when isVisible

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i having an activity with fragment. I can just open one fragment when i click on icon or something like this
But i want to close a fragment(or hide) with OnBackPressed method.

I create this:

```
private void onBackPressedInFragments(){
    if(backgroundSelectFragment != null && backgroundSelectFragment.isVisible())
    backgroundSelectFragment.getActivity().onBackPressed();
}
```

but when i open a fragment and click backbutton in Phone i just close the application. My Application have one activity and 2 fragments:

Here i create and showing the fragment:

```
 backgroundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (backgroundSelectFragment == null) {
                backgroundSelectFragment = new BackgroundSelectFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.main_relative, backgroundSelectFragment, "background")
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                        .show(backgroundSelectFragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                if (backgroundSelectFragment.isHidden()) {
                    showFragmentBackground();
                } else {
                    hideFragmentBackground();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

any idea guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed` in your activity. If there is any fragment in backstack than `popBackStack()` otherwise simply `finish()` your activity.

```
private boolean allowedToExit = false; // class level

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    // this is the last item
    if (backStackEntryCount == 1) {
        if (allowedToExit)
            finish();
        else {
            allowedToExit = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    allowedToExit = false;
                }
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
    }
    // we have more than 1 fragments in back stack
    if (backStackEntryCount > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```