# How to have onbackpress on navigation drawer(fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

This is my onbackpressed that i have on main page.How can i handle this challenge on my project.Such that on  one backpress to main page on double stop the app??? I have updated the java file
how can user click while one backpress from fragment to this home and on double to stop the app??

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
            android.app.Fragment fragment = new MenuFragment(); // create a fragement object
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
            ft.commit();


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    //this the email icon on the home page
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String myEmail[]={"john@balloonventures.com"};
                    Intent sendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,myEmail);
                    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"(Type your subject)");
                    sendMail.setType("plain/text");
                    //incase you have to add something else put here
                    sendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your phone:+2547");
                    startActivity(sendMail);


                }

            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    //taxi module
        public void taxi_id(View view){
            Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.Taxi.class);
            startActivity(timer);}
    //host home module
        public void hosthome_id(View view){
            Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(timer);}
        //calling enterprenuers module
        public void enter_id(View view){
            Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.SectionListView.class);
            startActivity(timer);}
        //calling UKV/ICV
        public void ukvicv_id(View view){
            Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.UkvIcv_Home.class);
            startActivity(timer);}
        public void finacial_id(View view){
            Intent finacial=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.FinacialHomePage.class);
            startActivity(finacial);}



        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.Menu.class);
            startActivity(timer);

        } 





        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void displayView(int viewId) {

            Fragment fragment = null;
            String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

            switch (viewId) {
                case R.id.nav_12wks_program:
                    Intent timer=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.ExpandableListMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(timer);

                    break;


                case R.id.nav_emergency_contact:
                    Intent flow=new Intent(this,sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.EmergencyContact.class);
                    startActivity(flow);

                    break;


                case R.id.nav_survey:
                    fragment = new SurveyFragment();
                    title = "Survey";
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_psld:
                    fragment = new PsldFragment();
                    title = "Psld";

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_security:
                    fragment = new SecurityFragment();
                    title = "All Volunteers Mu";

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_ukv:
                    fragment = new UkvKiswaFragment();
                    title = "Ukv's kiswahili";

                    break;

                case R.id.nav_agreement:
                    fragment = new AgreementFragment();
                    title = "Agreement ";

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_njoro_geo:
                    fragment = new GeoNjoroFragment();
                    title = "Njoro Geography ";

                    break;




            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            // set the toolbar title
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            displayView(item.getItemId());
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you are starting an activity in `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: i was just trying to on one click to go to main page

Comment: If I understood you right, you want to close the navigation drawer on single back press. Right?

Comment: i want to close fragment on single if some is in one ..then after your on the home page then another click you close

Comment: How you have implemented Navigation drawer? Have you used `NavigationView`? Please post your Main activity code with relevant navigation drawer code.

Comment: i have updated the main java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onBackPressed()` as below :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

You must added the fragment transactions to the backstack for proper back navigation of the fragments.

Change your `displayView(...)` as below :

```
...
..
if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null);//Note this
                ft.commit();
            }
...
..
```

Also change your onCreate() as below :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    android.app.Fragment fragment = new MenuFragment(); // create a fragement object
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);//Note this
    ft.commit();
...
..
}
```

Comment: i have this on my main java but on ist click it just stop the app when i have clicked from one of fragment

Comment: I think you are talking about the content fragments not navigation drawer.

Comment: yeah sorry for that

Comment: @FrancisNdirangu : Did it fixed your issue?

Comment: let me run then  i tell you

Comment: it 100% working this cool u have made my day ...i have been going through internet but getting the wrong one.Thanks for helping us grow as u grow in android ..

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer mechanism (50-100 milliseconds timer. You can use Timer, TimerTask classes) to know subsequent user clicks on back button and set some flag value based on the click and timer life cycle. If user taps twice before expiring the timer which means u have to quit the app other wise on timer expire go to main page.

Comment: give me a link of where i can find a link

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onBackPressed` if there is any fragment in backstack than `popBackStack()` otherwise simply `finish()` your activity.

For more details have a look into [How to close one fragment when isVisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980329/how-to-close-one-fragment-when-isvisible/40981113#40981113)